# UFW rule doesn't work

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, ufw

At first enable the ufw status.

```
root@sai:~# ufw status 
Status: active
```

It blocks both incoming and outgoing connections, tested by using ping 
ssh from both sides not working.

```
root@sai:~# ping 192.168.2.223
PING 192.168.2.223 (192.168.2.223) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C

--- 192.168.2.223 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms

root@sai:~# ssh durga@192.168.2.223
^C
```

Added a rule allow ssh, even after that also ssh doesn't work

```
root@sai:~# ufw allow ssh
Rule added
Rule added (v6)

root@sai:~# ssh durga@192.168.2.223


^C

root@sai:~# ufw status 
Status: active

To       Action      From

--       ------      ----

22        ALLOW       Anywhere

22 (v6)   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Suggest me the all possible commands..

Comment: show output of `sudo ufw status verbose`

Answer (score 0):

If `ufw` is configured to block outgoing traffic (which is not default policy) your `ssh` connection is blocked. You have to allow it.

```
sudo ufw allow out 22
```

On the server side `ufw` must be configured to allow incoming ssh connection (default port 22)

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```